# Statistics: How to identify dependent and independent variables in my dataset?

Tags: python, statistics

I am a little bit confused in the classification of dependent and independent variables in my dataset, on which I need to make a model for prediction. Any insights or how-to's would be very helpful here.
Suppose my dataset have 40 variables. In this case, it would be very difficult to classify the variables as independent or dependent. Are there any tests in python which can help us in identifying these?

Comment: @DYZ No. I just had a confusion while dealing with few types of datasets I faced recently. Thought of clarifying about this with experts here.

Comment: @DYZ Your aggrieved, hectoring tone is pointless self-indulgence; I have flagged your comment as unconstructive. If it's unclear to you what can usefully be said in this context, you can take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any given data set, labeling variables as dependent or independent is arbitrary -- there is no fundamental reason that one column should be independent and another should be dependent.

That said, typically it's conventional to say that "causes" are independent variables and "effects" are dependent variables. But this business about causes and effects is arbitrary too -- often enough there are several interacting variables, with each of the them "causing" the others, and each of them "affected" by the others.

The bottom line is that you should assign dependent and independent according to what you're trying to achieve. What is the most interesting or most useful variable in your data? Typically if that one is missing or has an unknown value, you'll have to estimate it from the other variables. In that case the interesting variable is the dependent variable, and all others are independent.

You'll probably get more interest in this question on stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insight on this. Actually, the fact you stated that "you should assign dependent and independent according to what you're trying to achieve." says it all. AFAIK, in a dataset, there will be few variables that will always effect each other and such neglecting them may cause errors in modelling I believe. Is there any tests we can perform during data munging part which can help us to deduce this info?

And as you pointed out, I will check out stackexchange as well on this. Thanks again.